dbt: How to Dynamically Union Several Models with the Same Schema
Context:
I'm creating a new table(s) every week with the same schema, and its name will always have the same prefix.
Table Examples:
Model 1 Name: avengers_au



name
date_birth
nationality




xyz
2024-01-04
au


abc
2024-01-05
au



Model 2 Name: avengers_us



name
date_birth
nationality




xyz
2024-01-04
us


abc
2024-01-05
us



...and so on and so forth
Current Solution
I'm manually doing UNION ALL every time I create a new table:
SELECT
   *
FROM
   avengers_au

UNION ALL

SELECT
   *
FROM
   avengers_us

... will add manually everytime there's a new table created

Question:
Is there any way in dbt that I can automate this process?

I'll provide you a pseudo-template of what I've done in the past. You can do this with either model refs or base sources. You just need to tweak the macro a bit depending on your situation. Also, my list of tables is static. If yours is dynamic, you can create a macro that retrieves the list from your DB platform's information schema, use some sort of naming convention on your models that you can list out programmatically, or simply update a list in dbt_project.yml as it changes (which is what I did).
First, I put my tables/refs in dbt_project.yml:
...
vars:
  avengers_sources:
    - model1
    - model2
    - model3
    ...

Then I have a simple macro that can return the list of models, similar to what the basic ref macro does. You can do the same thing with `source'.
{% macro refs(var_name) %}
  {% set ref_name_list = var(var_name) %}
  {% set models = [] %}

  {% for model in ref_name_list %}
    {% do models.append(builtins.ref(model)) %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% do return(models) %}
{% endmacro %}

Again, you can replace the above macro with one that queries an information schema, if needed.
And here's an example of how to use it in your model for unioning. Also in my example, I allow for including optional columns that may exist in some of your models, but not all.
my_model.sql:
WITH
{% set model_relations = refs('avengers_sources') %}

{% for model_relation in model_relations %}
  {{ model_relation.identifier}}_SOURCE AS (
    SELECT * FROM {{ model_relation }}
  ),
{% endfor %}

UNIONED AS (
  {% for model_relation in model_relations %}
    {%- set columns = dbt_utils.get_filtered_columns_in_relation(from=model_relation) -%}
    SELECT
        NAME,
        DATE_BIRTH,
        {% if 'NATIONALITY' in columns -%}
          NATIONALITY,
        {% else %}
          NULL::STRING NATIONALITY,
        {% endif %}
    FROM {{ model_relation.identifier}}_SOURCE
    {% if not loop.last %}
    UNION ALL
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
)

SELECT * FROM UNIONED

